# Excel - Split cell with a delimiter and if delimiter not found get complete cell value to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with data where I want a Split cell with a delimiter and if the delimiter is not found then copy that cell value to another cell

e.g.

ABC Ltd.

ABC Ltd. - Ind

PQR Ltd. - USA

LMN Corp.

**Output** - delimiter "-"

**ColumnA       ColumnB**

ABC Ltd.   ABC Ltd.

ABC Ltd.    Ind

PQR Ltd.     USA

LMN Corp.    LMN Corp.

However, I'm using below formula but not getting what I want.

=TRIM(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))

=TRIM(REPLACE(B2,1,FIND("-",B2),""))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put in error handling for the case where B2 doesn't contain a '-'

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1)),TRIM(B2))
```

and

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(REPLACE(B2,1,FIND("-",B2),"")),TRIM(B2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

[image]

Formula:

`=IF(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))>0,RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)-1),A1)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach (doesn't necessarily mean better though ;) )

## 1

```
=TRIM(LEFT(B2&"-",FIND("-",B2&"-",1)-1))
```

## 2

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```